# JSON objects not sending from XMLHttpRequest to express

Tags: javascript, ajax, express

I'm trying to send a JSON object to an express server. This is my code for the client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Express demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="sendUrlEncoded()">Send an application/x-www-form-urlencoded POST request</button>
<button onclick="sendJson()">Send an application/json POST request</button>
<div id="response"></div>
<script>
function sendUrlEncoded() {
    var data = "text=stuff";
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.send(data);
}

function sendJson() {
    var data = {text:"stuff"};
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    http.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the server:

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Received request");
    console.log(req.headers);
    console.log(req.body);
    next();
});

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    console.log("GET request");
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index.html"));
});

app.post("*", function(req, res) {
    console.log("Received post request");
    res.status=200;
});

var server = app.listen(3001, function() {console.log("Listening on port 3001")});
```

sendJson() was formerly "sendPost()" in the original version of this question. When the client sends a GET request or an XMLHttpRequest, the server always receives it. If it's a GET request or sent via sendUrlEncoded(), it contains the data in the body and calls the app.get() function successfully. However, with sendJson(), the server only gets the request in the general message handler. It doesn't call app.get(), and the request's body is {}. In addition, the header is not quite what I expect:

```
{
  host: 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3001',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  accept: '*/*',
  'access-control-request-method': 'POST',
  'access-control-request-headers': 'content-type',
  origin: 'http://192.168.0.102:3001',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  referer: 'http://192.168.0.102:3001/',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
}
```

Note: I replaced the real IP address with xx.xxx.xxx.xxx above. If you can help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: how are you calling sendPost?

Comment: I haven't heard of a sendPost method. Every tutorial I've seen says you use the XMLHttpRequest send method and specify "POST" as the method when you open it.

Comment: sendPost is you function ! :) the function within which the ajax object is instantiated - how you call it?

Comment: It's called on a button click, and I know that it's called successfully. I also know that express is receiving a POST request. However, the body is empty, and the header looks strange:

Comment: Instead of 'content-type': 'application/json', it has   'access-control-request-method': 'POST',   'access-control-request-headers': 'content-type'.

Comment: And express never calls the .post() handler, which it does do correctly when I send an x-www-form-encoded message.

Comment: I edited the original post heavily to make this more clear. Hope you can help me out!

Answer (score 1):

[Edited]
You still need to remove the middleware before the `app.get` endpoint because it only adds some noise, and also end the request by sending the response back to the user, else the server will hang. In your previous code, you only set the response status to 200 but did not end the response with `send` or `end`
**The issue, most importantly** is caused by the wildcard * that is used in both post requests. Just use two different endpoints for your requests.

See below.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// create application/json parser
// this will only handle application/json requests
// and will be passed to the route handler as middleware

var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()

// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })

// POST /urlencoded (fictitious endpoint) gets urlencoded bodies
// Test with your forms
app.post('/urlencoded', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
    res.send('welcome, ' + JSON.stringify(req.body))
})

// POST / gets JSON bodies
// Test with application/json

app.post('/', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
    console.log("Received post request for application/json type");
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body)).end();
})

app.listen(3001, function () {
    console.log("Listening on port 3001")
});
```

When I change the request to `application/json`, we get the expected result, which in this case is the request body echoed back.

[image]

And server logs:

```
Listening on port 3001
Received post request for application/json type
{ test: 'some stuff to show' }
```

**You cannot set two different content-types for your requests**.
So you either send `application/json` type or you send `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Is this what you are after?

Comment: I removed the middleware and send the response back to the user, but that unfortunately didn't help. The server hanging was never the issue in the first place. The problem appears to be that either

1. AJAX isn't sending application/json requests properly, or
2. Express is receiving application/json requests improperly.

Whether or not the middleware/sending the response back to the client is included or not, x-www-form-urlencoded requests still send and receive correctly. It's only application/json requests that don't, despite the code being virtually identical.

Comment: ah, ok I see now. Working on it and will update answer shortly

Comment: I made a little progress. When I try to send an application/json request, the following error lots in the browser console:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3001/' from origin 'http://192.168.0.102:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
(index):26 POST http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3001/ net::ERR_FAILED
sendJson @ (index):26
onclick @ (index):9

So it looks like the issue is upstream of express.

Comment: By accessing the program via the WAN IP rather than the local IP, this error resolves and express does receive the application/json POST request. However, the issue remains that the body is simply {} even though data is being send.

Comment: And this in turn was because I'd commented out app.use(bodyParser.json()). Adding that back in resolved the issue. Thanks for trying to help me out, rags21riches!

Comment: That is a different issue. But I am glad you sorted it out. Keep up the good work

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was accessing my server from a LAN IP when I should have been accessing it from a WAN IP. I had also commented out app.use(bodyParser.json()). The former issue prevented the request from sending properly from the client, and raised an error in the browser console. The latter error prevented express from receiving the json object in the body of the request.

I solved these problems as follows:

To enable CORS, I added:

```
var cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
```

To enable express to receive JSON from application/json POST requests, I added:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

For future n00bz like myself, I found [this article](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/what-is-cors) helpful for explaining about CORS.